# Async.waterfall, foreach and parsing JSON node.js. Need some advices

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, foreach

My task is a parsing last 100 dota2 games. I work with dota 2 API and small lib from jiiin (https://github.com/jiin/dota2api)

All of i have, it's one async.waterfall call. Like this:

```
exports.get = function(req, res, next) {
var playerID = +req.params.id;
var playerCounter = [];
var playerInfo = {
    kills: [],
    deaths: [],
    assists: [],
    last_hits: [],
    denies: [],
    hero_damage: [],
    hero_healing: [],
    gold_spent: [],
    kills_number: 0,
    deaths_number: 0,
    assists_number: 0
};

async.waterfall([

    function getDota2Json(callback) {
        dota.getByAccountID(playerID, function (err, result) {
            callback(err, result);
        });
    },
    function getMatches(result, callback) {
        result.matches.forEach(function (match) {
            callback(null, match.match_id);
        });
    },
    function getMatchInfo(matchID, callback) {
        dota.getMatchDetails(matchID, function (err, result) {
            callback(err, result.players);
        });
    },
    function getCurrentPlayer(players, callback) {
        players.forEach(function (player) {
            if (player.account_id === playerID) {
                callback(null, player);
            }
        });
    },
    function getDamage(player, callback) {
        callback(null,
                player.kills,
                player.deaths,
                player.assists,
                player.last_hits,
                player.denies,
                player.hero_damage,
                player.hero_healing,
                player.gold_spent,
                '1');
    }
], function (err, kills, deaths, assists, last_hits, denies, hero_damage, hero_healing, gold_spent, counter) {
    playerCounter.push(counter);

    playerInfo.kills.push(kills);
    playerInfo.deaths.push(deaths);
    playerInfo.assists.push(assists);

    console.log(playerCounter.length);

    if (playerCounter.length === 100) {

        playerInfo.kills.forEach(function (val) {
            playerInfo.kills_number += val;
        });
        console.log('Last 100 K ' + playerInfo.kills_number);

        playerInfo.deaths.forEach(function (val) {
            playerInfo.deaths_number += val;
        });
        console.log('Last 100 D ' + playerInfo.deaths_number);

        playerInfo.assists.forEach(function (val) {
            playerInfo.assists_number += val;
        });
        console.log('Last 100 A ' + playerInfo.assists_number);


        var magickOpts = [
            "-background", "grey60",
            "-bordercolor", "snow",
            "-border", "6",
            "-fill", "black",
            "-pointsize", "50",
            "label: Dota 2 LAST 100 \n K - D - A " + playerInfo.kills_number + ' - ' + playerInfo.deaths_number + ' - ' + playerInfo.assists_number,
            ""+playerID+".png"
        ];
        var im = spawn('convert', magickOpts);
    }
});

res.end('rdy');
```

};

I think it's not good code, but I can't find alternative. Dota API take me 100 games in JSON, but I need to "forEach" with game_id for details and "forEach" with player_id for details for current player in request.params.id. And after all, I again use forEach for summary data. It's right way?) Or I rly stupid?)

May be you have some ideas to do this faster? May be need use MongoDB (?) or another stuff.

At the end I generate simple image with statistics.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you might be able to use [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) to simplify some of your `forEach` calls...

This might be a small nitpick but to get a sum of an Array of numbers you can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of Arrays.

```
playerInfo.kills_number = playerInfo.kills.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
```